# Select dentro de select ordenado pela segunda consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou com um problema, não sei se estou fazendo da maneira correta, mas vamos lá.

Tenho uma tabela que lista alguns funcionários ( tblTecnicos ).

Tenho outra tabela , que tem o cadastros de serviços que esses técnicos realizaram (tblServicos) , nessa tabela , tem um campo que chama "tipoServico", nele  , tem o id de algum serviço que o técnico realizou.

Ex : Serviços :

1 - manutençao
2 - formatacao

Na tabela tblServicos

- idTecnico     tipoServico
- 5               2
- 5               1
- 2               2
- 1               1
- 5               2
- 2               1

Tipo , se eu colocar para listar os tecnico , listaria :

- idTecnico 1
- idTecnico 2
- idTecnico 5

etc

Eu gostaria de fazer um select , listando todos os tecnicos , ordenado pela maior quantidade de servicos que eles realizaram.

No exemplo , o técnico com ID 1 fez 1 serviço , o tecnico com id 2 fez 2 serviços  e o técnico com ID 5 fez 3 serviços.

Na hora de realizar o select , gostaria que viesse ordenado pela maior quantidade de servicos que realizaram.

- idTecnico 5
- idTecnico 2
- idTecnico 1

Tentei dessa forma , mas nao deu certo :

```
SELECT * FROM tblTecnicos where (select count(tipoServico) from tblServicos where tipoServico > 0 order by(tipoServico)DESC)
```

Alguém sabe se dá para fazer?

## EDIÇÃO

Consegui resolver parte do problema com o codigo abaixo , mas ele só esta retornando 1 resultado. O que esta errado ?

```
SELECT tblTecnicos.nome, count(tblServicos.tipoServico) 
FROM tblTecnicos 
    INNER JOIN tblServicos ON tblServicos.tipoServico > 0
AND tblTecnicos.id = tblServicos.idTecnico 
ORDER BY tblServicos.tipoServico DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que tens de fazer o `count` do `tipoServico` no `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblTecnicos 
WHERE tipoServico > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(tipoServico) DESC
```

Caso querias apresentar o resultado apresentando (apenas o `idTecnico`), tens de fazer ainda um `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT idTecnico 
FROM tblTecnicos 
WHERE tipoServico > 0
GROUP BY idTecnico 
ORDER BY COUNT(tipoServico) DESC
```

Comment: Boa tarde Cesar , blz ? Mas , a coluna tipoServico pertence a tabela tblServicos e não há tabela tblTecnicos . Executando do jeito que voce falou , da erro

Comment: Certo, não tinha reparado. Sendo assim tens de fazer um join com a tabela dos serviços. Diz me qual a relação entre as duas tabelas. O `id` da tblServicos corresponde ao `idTecnico` da `tblTecnicos `??

Answer (score 0):

Depois de estudar um pouco sobre o `JOIN` do MYSQL, consegui resolver meu problema .

Segue como ficou:

```
SELECT a.id,a.nome,count(b.tipoServico) 
FROM tblTecnicos AS a 
INNER JOIN tblServico AS b 
ON (a.id = b.idTecnico) 
GROUP BY a.nome 
ORDER BY COUNT(b.tipoServico) DESC 
LIMIT 12
```